# Smarty/PHP loop not being passed to IE(Pc) or Chrome/FF(Mac)

Tags: php, internet-explorer, macos, smarty

I've been working on a site that has a lot of PHP/Smarty involved, I've been asked to re-skin a webstore checkout process, but during this we've discovered this issue. This particular quirk is one part of a tax calculation that doesn't get sent to the browser in IE for PC and Chrome/FF for the Mac. It's NOT in the output source in the browsers, but is in FF, Chrome and Opera on the PC.

Here is the code that doesn't "work:"

```
{foreach $cart.taxes.$currency as $tax}
    <div id="subTotalCaption2"><p style="width:100px;">{$tax.name_lang}:</p></div>
        <div id="taxAmount2"><p>{$tax.formattedAmount}</p></div>
{/foreach}
```

It's not a CSS issue as if you go all the way through the checkout process and then back to the order page (Not using the back button, using the on-site links) it works. There is another calculation on the last page of the process that does the same thing:

```
{foreach from=$order.taxes.$currency item="tax"}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="{$colspan}" class="tax">{$tax.name_lang}:</td>
            <td>{$tax.formattedAmount}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
```

I guess my question is what could cause this to not be read (Parsed?) in IE and the mac but other browsers do it fine on the PC.

The System installed on the site is the [Livecart](http://www.livecart.com) system (if anyone is familiar with that, I doubt it though), developed in Lithuania I think. If anyone has heard of that. I'm not so sure it's that stable, all I've done is made some CSS/Layout changes and then this entire function disappears.

The site is [euroworker.no](http://www.euroworker.no/order). You'll have to add an item into the basket (Kjøp and handlevogn).

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to debug on PHP level (print_r the `$order` array and check for differences). There is no reason for HTML not being output on Mac based browsers. You are not using any Ajax here?

Comment: Hi Again Pekka, I honestly don't know much about how to debug this or if Ajax is being used. How can I find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing 
`{foreach $cart.taxes.$currency as $tax}` 
with 
`{foreach from=$cart.taxes.$currency item=tax}`